# Equivalent of Matlab's uigetfile in Mathematica

Tags: dynamic, import

I was wondering if there an equivalent of the "uigetfile" Matlab function to use it in *Mathematica*.

To be more precise, I want to read many Excel files and I don't want to type a static path; instead, I want to be able to go each time and search for it, like in the browse window.

Here what I want to do in steps:

1. Search the directory of my Excel files using the "SystemDialogInput" probably, in order get the path of the directory.
2. Store the directory in a string.
3. Load the name of all the Excel files inside the this directory.
4. Make a loop and read each of the Excel files based on some condition then perform some calculations.

Comment: Please describe in more detail how you would like this to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While I wait for a more complete description of your needs please see:

- [How to | Insert a File Path](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/howto/InsertAFilePath.html)
- [`FileNameSetter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FileNameSetter.html)
- [`SystemDialogInput`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SystemDialogInput.html)

And try:

```
FrontEndTokenExecute["FileNameDialog"]
```

Or:

```
SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]
```

Answer (score 8):

You probably want a workflow similar to this. First locate one or more Excel files:

```
files = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen", {NotebookDirectory[], {"Excel File" ->{"*.xlsx","*.xls"}}},
WindowTitle -> "Import Excel File"];
```

Then import the selected files and do something with the imported data (what that something is, we don't know so no point in speculating):

```
If[files =!= $Canceled && files =!= $Failed,
(* a single file will be a string, several files will be in a list *)
 tmp = Which[
StringQ[files], Import[files],
ListQ[files], Import /@ files,
True, (* some warning message *)
];
 (* then do something with tmp *)
 ]
```

**Edit**

If you want to import csv files then change

```
{"Excel File" -> {"*.xlsx","*.xls"}}
```

to

```
{"CSV File" -> {"*.csv"}}
```

If you would like to choose between Excel and CSV then

```
{"Excel File" -> {"*.xlsx", "*.xls"}, "CSV File" -> {"*.csv"}}
```

If you would like both Excel and CSV to be available to select then

```
{"Excel or CSV File" -> {"*.xlsx", "*.xls", "*.csv"}}
```

...and so on.

Comment: I managed to form a string now that has now all the files in repertory for example "basecase", how to keep only csv files?

Comment: @kevin please see my edit

Comment: +1 for teaching me `Unsame`

Comment: Thx a lot..it is more clear

Answer (score 1):

It seems more consistent with the Matlab uigetfile function to say

```
fnams = FileNames["*.xlsx"|"*.xls"];
selectedFile = ChoiceDialog["Choose File", fnams];
sheet=Import[selectedFile]
```